# Convert PUG to Javascript/JQuery

Tags: jquery, pug

The PUG version of the code is below.

```
- var messages = getMessages()
            if messages.info
                each msg in messages.info
                    div(class='alert alert-info alert-dismissable'  role='button' data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hide!") #{msg}
            if messages.error
                each msg in messages.error
                    div(class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissable' role='button' data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hide!") #{msg}

            if messages.success
                each msg in messages.success
                    div(class='alert alert-success alert-dismissable' role='button' data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hide!") #{msg}
```

I need to convert it to Javascript/Jquery format.
I did get the fixes for `if statements` (I put enclosing brackets), however, how should I do the `iteration` part.

Should it be something like

```
$.each(messages.info, function( index, value ) {
   $('div(class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissable' role='button' data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hide!")')value
});
```

Comment: you have already solved the problem.. just add a check over $.each.. for `if(messages.info){ $.each(messages.info, function(i,e){}); }`

Answer (score 0):

My apologies for raising such a question. Anyway, as @atulquest93 said, I've already solved it. However, it wasn't 100% correct. Below is the final version.

```
 var messages = getMessages()
    if (messages.info){
        $.each(messages.info, function( index, value ) {
            $('<div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissable" role="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hide!">'+value+'</div>')
        });
    }

    if (messages.error){
        $.each(messages.info, function( index, value ) {
            $('<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable" role="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hide!">'+value+'</div>')
        });
    }
    if (messages.error){
        $.each(messages.info, function( index, value ) {
            $('<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable" role="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hide!">'+value+'</div>')
        });
    }
```

Also, this [pug to html and vice versa](http://html2jade.org/) to convert pug/jade code to html and vice versa on the fly. Cheers!